# Is FirebaseInstanceIdService onTokenRefresh() only called when the app is running?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Pretty much as the title suggests, if I have an Android app registered for FCM notifications and the app is in background or hasn't been launched in a while and the token changes, when is `onTokenRefresh()` called?

Will it wake the app to call `onTokenRefresh()` or will it just be called the next time the app is launched?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The events when the `onTokenRefresh()` is triggered is already included in the [FirebaseInstanceIdService documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService):

> Called when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed. The application should call getToken() and send the tokens to all application servers.
>
> This will not be called very frequently, it is needed for key rotation and to handle Instance ID changes due to:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - App is restored on a new device
> - User uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - User clears app data
>
> The system will throttle the refresh event across all devices to avoid overloading application servers with token updates.

And as also specified, the FirebaseInstanceIdService class extends the [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class, which can run regardless if the app is in foreground or background.

Comment: What happens when user updates app from gcm to fcm & then doesn't open app.Will message delivered to a user or is it unreachable ?

Comment: @ronakPoriya Migrating your app from GCM to FCM should not have any changes to the behavior when it comes to the delivery of the message.

Comment: Message delivery code is migrated to class MyFirebaseMessagingService.Since onTokenRefresh() from FirebaseInstanceIdService not called, That would not work.Have I understood correctly?

Comment: @RonakPoriya Sorry. I wasn't able to understand your statement. I would suggest posting a question with the details you have. From there, I think the community would be able to help you better. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what `onTokenRefresh()` will be call.

1. The app is installed.
2. The token is compromised.
3. The token is Changed.

So for you short answer is The `onTokenRefresh()` method will trigger regardless your app is in foreground or background.