# How to ensure renewed Firebase token is still workable for previous registered device?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an Android app and managed to set up Firebase Instance Messaging in my app. Howerver, I realize that when I open my app again after 5-6 days without open it, the token renewed/refreshed. And I pretty sure I didn't do any of following (based on FCM documentation):

> *The app is restored on a new device.
> *The user uninstalls/reinstall the app.
> *The user clears app data.

But I'm not sure how is this really being done (by the app itself):

> *The app deletes Instance ID.

Anyway, is that the new registration token is refreshed only after the app is relaunch (i.e. launched after 5-6 days like my case)?
Would the old token is still workable in receive push notification / instance cloud messaging **before the app relaunch (i.e. trigger the `onTokenRefresh()` )** ?
Or is it the `onTokenRefresh()` could be even silently running at the background?

So, I'm wondering how those expert chatting apps cater for this kind of scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the app doesn't *delete the Instance ID* on it's own, unless you explicitly call it (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42640129/4625829)).

If [`onTokenRefresh()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#onTokenRefresh()) is triggered, is is the developer's responsibility to call `getToken()` to retrieve the *new and valid* Registration Token, send it to their App Server and delete the old one. As stated in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation):

> After you've obtained the token, you can send it to your app server and store it using your preferred method.

`onTokenRefresh()` can be triggered regardless if the app is in foreground or background (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41582347/4625829)). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686075/4625829) by @DiegoGiorgini has an excellent explanation on how it works.